# Node base error

Tags: tikz-pgf

Encountering a strange issue here: I have a node style that I have been using for many flow-charts. It's base has always been in the exact center of the shape, but now i'ts been translated up about 1/4 toward the north anchor. The blue and red lines clearly show it's moved north, but the `diamond`'s base is still in the exact center. What gives?

[image: node base]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%\input{../tikz-setup.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning, matrix}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, 
                        draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em ,
                        minimum width = 6em,
                        inner sep = 5pt
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 3pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]
\tikzstyle{data}    = [ trapezium, 
                        draw, 
                        trapezium left angle=60, 
                        trapezium right angle=120pt,
                        minimum height = 6em, 
                        text width = 5em,
                        inner xsep = 0pt
                       ]
\tikzstyle{line}    = [ draw, -triangle 45 ]

\tikzstyle{list}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        minimum width = 6em                      
                      ]

\tikzstyle{ptr-box}  = [ rectangle, 
                        text width = 8em                      
                      ]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = flush center, font = \small]

    \matrix [matrix of nodes, column sep = 1em, row sep = 2em,
                nodes={},
                ] (end-mtrx)
    {     
    |[action] (a)| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \\
    |[test] (b)| Lorem ipsum dolo  \\        
    |[test] (c)| Lorem ipsum  \\ 
    |[test] (d)| Lorem ipsum dolor & |[action] (e)| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \\
    |[state] (f)| Lorem ipsum d & |[state] (g)| Lorem ipsum dolor  & |[state] (bad-sd)| Lorem ipsum dolo\\
     };

     \path[draw, red, line width=5pt] (d.base) -- (e.base);

     \path[draw, blue, line width=5pt] (a.base) -- +(3,0);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `.base` denotes  the baseline of the node, the first line's base to be exact. Try `.center`.

Comment: Ok, well I'm more concerned with why the bases (which I believe is what a `matrix of nodes` uses to position them) of the `action` / `rectangle` are off. I want to figure out why they are not lining up like they used to (with the `center`s aligned).

Comment: the `base` anchor will remain unaltered whether you have one line of text or add more lines of text in a node; in your case, it's not the base anchor that has shifted; the anchor remained unaltered, but you added more lines of text.

Comment: So the node shifted down because I have more lines of text? I'm not understanding why that happened. I have a previous example of a regular `matrix` where I have a `action` & `test` (from my styles) side by side and their `center`s are on the same y-coordinate.

Comment: Use `nodes={draw,anchor=center}` in the matrix specification to align them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nodes normally align at their baseline.

You can shift that with the `anchor` key (section 16.5 "Positioning Nodes" of the `PFG/TikZ` manual).
I'd add `anchor=center` to the matrix specification:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = flush center, font = \small]
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, column sep = 1em, row sep = 2em,
                nodes={anchor=center},
                ] (end-mtrx)
    {     
    |[action] (a)| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \\
    |[test] (b)| Lorem ipsum dolo  \\        
    |[test] (c)| Lorem ipsum  \\ 
    |[test] (d)| Lorem ipsum dolor & |[action] (e)| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \\
    |[state] (f)| Lorem ipsum d & |[state] (g)| Lorem ipsum dolor  & |[state] (bad-sd)| Lorem ipsum dolo\\
     };

     \path[draw, red, line width=5pt] (d.center) -- (e.center);
     \path[draw, blue, line width=5pt] (a.center) -- +(3,0);
     \path[draw, red,] (d.base) -- (e.base);
     \path[draw, blue,] (a.base) -- +(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Output

[image: output of example]

Comment: Strange that I hadn't run into this before since I haven't had to add `anchor=center` to any of my previous charts. Oh well... Thanks!

Comment: @blitzvergnugen If the nodes in a row have the same number of lines there is no difference in aligning. (The `center`s are at the same `y`-coordinate.)